# Why does plotting this equation not generate the correct curve?

Tags: matlab, octave, trigonometry

The intention is to plot the following equation: P*sin(x)/x + cos(x), for P = 1.6 and x in [0, 5], which, ignoring the green-filled areas, should look someting like:

[image]

However, from the following code:

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : 5;     % ka/pi, where k-wavevector, a-lattice spacing.

P = 1.6;              % 2*m*U_0 / hbar^2.
rhs =  P * sinc(x*pi) + cos(x*pi);
rhs2 = P * ( sin(x*pi) / x*pi) + cos(x*pi);

plot(x, rhs, '--b', x, rhs2, 'b', x, -1*ones(size(x)), 'r', x, 1*ones(size(x)), 'r')
axis([0 5 -3 3])
xlabel('ka/pi')
legend('P*sinc(x) + cos(x)', '(2mU_0b)/(hbar^2) * sin(ka)/ka + cos(ka)', 'y = -1', 'y = 1')
```

what I currently get is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

---

I am on Windows 10, Octave-4.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MATLAB definition of the [`sinc`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html) is `sinc(t) = sin(pi t)/(pi t)`, i.e. you must not multiply by `pi` in the rhs definition:

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : 5;     % ka/pi, where k-wavevector, a-lattice spacing.

P = 1.6;              % 2*m*U_0 / hbar^2.
rhs =  P * sinc(x)+ cos(x*pi);
rhs2 = P * (sin(x*pi) / x*pi) + cos(x*pi);

plot(x, rhs, 'b', x, rhs2, '--b', x, -1*ones(size(x)), 'r', x, 1*ones(size(x)), 'r')
axis([0 5 -3 3])
xlabel('ka/\pi')
legend('P*sinc(x) + cos(x)', '(2mU_0b)/(hbar^2) * sin(ka)/ka + cos(ka)', 'y = -1', 'y = 1')
```

[image]

Also note that for `t=0` `sinc(t)=1`, whereas your `rhs2` has `sin(x pi)/(x pi)`, which for `x=0` returns `NaN`, hence the difference in the two signals, as the second is a pure cosine.

---

I missed the element wise division and lack of brackets in the OP's `sinc` implementation, see [am304's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315927/5211833) for that. Note that even when using element wise division and brackets you'll still miss the point at `x=0`, since that'll result to `NaN`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- the first one, as Adriaan pointed out, is incorrect use of the `sinc` function.
- the second one, is you forgot to do the element-wise division when implementing your own version of `sinc`

Here's the corrected version - note the `./`:

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : 5;     % ka/pi, where k-wavevector, a-lattice spacing.

P = 1.6;              % 2*m*U_0 / hbar^2.
rhs =  P * sinc(x)+ cos(x*pi);
rhs2 = P * (sin(x*pi) ./ (x*pi)) + cos(x*pi);

plot(x, rhs, 'b', x, rhs2, '--b', x, -1*ones(size(x)), 'r', x, 1*ones(size(x)), 'r')
axis([0 5 -3 3])
xlabel('ka/pi')
legend('P*sinc(x) + cos(x)', '(2mU_0b)/(hbar^2) * sin(ka)/ka + cos(ka)', 'y = -1', 'y = 1')
```

And the resulting plot is:

[image]